# onCreateAnimation not getting called in DialogFragment?

Tags: android

I'm trying to gain access to the onCreateAnimation callback within a DialogFragment. The animations are being added to the DialogFragment within the onCreateView callback like below.

```
        // Set Animation
    if (getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
        getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations =  R.style.DialogFragmentSlideTheme;
    }
```

And my onCreateAnimation method is pretty barebones but looks like this

```
@Override
public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim)
{
    return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), nextAnim);
}
```

I set a breakpoint but it doesn't seem to ever get called?

The animations from the style are such

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="50%p"
    android:toXDelta="0" />
<alpha
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

And are referenced in the styles like below

```
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/android_enter_from_right</item>
```

Comment: Your animation is an `Animation` resource or an `Animator` resource?

Comment: Updated the post with code from the animation ^

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this issue?